# Attempted to use a closed Session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a similar question, and I can't find the bug.

This is my code:

```
 # create a data structure to hold user context
context = {}

ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
def classify(sentence):
    # generate probabilities from the model
    results = model.predict([bow(sentence, words)])
    # filter out predictions below a threshold
    results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD]
    # sort by strength of probability
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append((classes[r[0]], r[1]))
    # return tuple of intent and probability
    return return_list

def response(sentence, userID='123', show_details=False):
    results = classify(sentence)
    # if we have a classification then find the matching intent tag
    if results:
        # loop as long as there are matches to process
        while results:
            for i in intents['intents']:
                # find a tag matching the first result
                if i['tag'] == results[0][0]:
                    # set context for this intent if necessary
                    if 'context_set' in i:
                        if show_details: print ('context:', i['context_set'])
                        context[userID] = i['context_set']

                    # check if this intent is contextual and applies to this user's conversation
                    if not 'context_filter' in i or \
                        (userID in context and 'context_filter' in i and i['context_filter'] == context[userID]):
                        if show_details: print ('tag:', i['tag'])
                        # a random response from the intent
                        return 
                    print(random.choice(i['responses']))

results.pop(0)

classify("today")
```

But I got the error:

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) in () ----> 1 classify("
> today")
>
> in classify(sentence) 5 def classify(sentence): 6 # generate
> probabilities from the model ----> 7 results =
> model.predict([bow(sentence, words)]) 8 # filter out predictions below
> a threshold 9 results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if
> r>ERROR_THRESHOLD]
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.pyc in
> predict(self, X) 255 """ 256 feed_dict = feed_dict_builder(X, None,
> self.inputs, None) --> 257 return self.predictor.predict(feed_dict)
> 258 259 def predict_label(self, X):
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/evaluator.pyc in
> predict(self, feed_dict) 67 prediction = [] 68 if len(self.tensors) ==
> 1: ---> 69 return self.session.run(self.tensors[0],
> feed_dict=feed_dict) 70 else: 71 for output in self.tensors:
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc
> in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata) 776 try: 777
> result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr, --> 778
> run_metadata_ptr) 779 if run_metadata: 780 proto_data =
> tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc
> in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata) 959
> 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, ' 960 'which has shape
> %r' --> 961 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name,
> str(subfeed_t.get_shape()))) 962 if not
> self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t): 963 raise ValueError('Tensor %s may
> not be fed.' % subfeed_t)
>
> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (48,) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 48)'

Can anyone please tell me why its shape can't fit?

Comment: what type of data you feed this network what the right shape for this data

Answer (score 0):

you have feed you model with data has a shape of `(48,)` you must reshape it to `(?,48)`

```
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros(48)
print(data.shape)
#>>>(48,)
data =np.array([data])
print(data.shape)
#>>>(1, 48)
```

Comment: just  put the input data  in `np.array([data])` that will give you the right shape